# Inconsistent response time with socket communications

Tags: windows, networking, sockets

I have a test setup with two custom-made devices of the same type, Ethernet switch and industrial PC.
The switch is Moxa EDS 405 and the PC is a relatively low spec machine with Atom 1.46 GHz CPU, 4 Gb RAM and Intel I210 Ethernet controller.

The devices support data transfer via sockets. They are intended to be connected to the PC via the switch and polled from the application running on the PC. The application uses .Net methods ***socket.Send*** and ***socket.Receive*** for data transfer to and from the devices.

I've noticed a strange inconsistency with response time when the application polls both devices and when the application polls only one device. Basically, when I have one device connected to the PC, the average timespan to send and receive the data (the time to execute ***socket.Send*** and ***socket.Receive*** methods) is about 1.2 seconds. But when I connect both devices, this time increases to 11.1 seconds for either device.

What causes such rapid increase in send/receive operations duration when working with both devices? Is it due to the limitation of the PC specs, so it somehow cannot process the inbound data flow from two devices fast enough?

*Update:*
The app sends two kinds of requests to the devices. Requests of the first type is just a textual command "Status", just a string. Upon receiving the command, the device sends back two bytes of data representing its internal state. This is the process that takes either 1.2 or 11.1 seconds depending on the number of devices connected. When working with both devices the app uses two separate threads to talk to each device and sends the status commands approximately every 10 minutes. Time schedules of each threads are not synced with each other and can be slightly changed by the app itself depending on the operating conditions.
Requests of the second kind are data requests. The app sends "GetFile" command and receives approimately 37 kbytes of data in return. This happens every 1 hour. I didn't track the duration of this procedure, but it takes less than 100 seconds, since I have the socket timeout set to 100 seconds and it never caused an exception in the app.

*Update:*
The diagram clarifying my connection scheme is by the link below. The left case is when two devices are connected and the app polls both of them. Socket send and receive time is 11.1 seconds in this case. The right case is with only one device, and the corresponding time here is 1.2 seconds.

Connection diagram:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your setup is not very clear. Could you include in your post a schema of your network?

Comment: @harrymc I've added a link to the diagram image. This is my first question here, so I can't add an image directly to the question.

Comment: Did it for you. The question first is what does the program do and how much data is it sending. 1.2 seconds for send/receive on a local network sounds excessive.

Comment: Thanks for adding the image. I updated my question with the description of the app logic and the data it exchanges with the devices.